# curious case of two log files in sql database

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

I was doing a POC(proof of concept) for which I created two log files in a test database. I created a table and inserted 10000 rows. I observed that both my log files were getting used.
I know that logs are written serially, and in my case both log files have space on disk with autogrowth enabled, then why my second log file was getting used? Why not use a single log file and move on to second log file when space is not available. Isn't it supposed to be like this.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard warning about not using multiple log files etc etc.

You have two log files and are wondering why the first one didn't grow to fill all of the available disk space (or limit on the file size) before moving on to the second file. Correct?

A little bit of pre-information.  Log files are broken up into multiple virtual log files (VLFs).  If you search for VLF you can find a lot of information on them and when you have too many or too few, but that's a different subject.

If it helps you can think of the multiple log files as a single big circle.  The log information will be written round and round in that circle.  As each VLF is filled up the next is checked until it hits a VLF that is already in use.  Only at that point will there be an autogrowth.  I believe the currently used file will be the one autogrown.  If it can't be (file size limit or out of disk space) then the next file is checked and so on.  Only if none of the files can be grown will you get an out of space error.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345419(v=sql.105).aspx)...

> If the log contains multiple physical log files, the logical log will move through all the physical log files before it wraps back to the start of the first physical log file.

so in your case,the First Physical log file must have been full,so the SQLServer might have started writing to Second log file when you have checked.

Answer (score 1):

Log files don't work like data files. With **data** files, you expect to see filling of the files within a single filegroup is done *proportionally*

You will not see the same behavior with the transaction log.

The transaction log is written to *sequentially*. As a result, you will see only one file written to at a time. When that file is full, SQL Server will then begin to write to the other file. Paul Randall has a [detailed blog post on the circular nature of the log](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-more-on-the-circular-nature-of-the-log/).

You should look into removing the second file, and using only a single (properly sized) transaction log file.